# Aligning latex3 boxes side by side

Tags: paragraphs, alignment, latex3, box

I'm building a token list by adding dynamically generated boxes to it inside a `map`-function, but the result only looks correct when it's inside a paragraph or a table cell. When they are the first ting in a paragraph, they show up one above the other.

I want the boxes to be flush against each other, side by side. I've experimented with wrapping the whole thing in `\hbox_set:Nw ⟨box⟩ ⟨contents⟩ \hbox_set_end:`, but could not get that working with the map function.

Simplified example showing the stacked boxes when they begin a paragraph:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\twoboxes}{m}
 {
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \hfill #1 }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \box_use:N \l_tmpa_box }
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpb_box { \hfill #1 }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { \box_use:N \l_tmpb_box }
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

result inside a paragraph: \twoboxes{test}, looks correct

\twoboxes{test} is the result when beginning a new paragraph

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\leavevmode` before `\hbox`. For more information, study, how TeX changes between vertical and horizontal mode.

Comment: Aha, thanks! If you post that as the answer, I will accept it :)

Comment: Have you considered using `coffin`s rather than `box`es? They make alignment easier (generally) and you can join them together.

Comment: I did look at them shortly, but they seemed much more complicated — and either way `\leavevmode` works for my use case so far :)